# Traverse Json objects inside Arrays in Rego

Tags: json, terraform, opa, rego

I want to get the value of client_broker key and check if it is TLS or not ,if TLS the rego should pass else it will fail,but i am not able to traverse the nested json within the array element,tried using walk but not working,,,need help :(

Was trying using the below code but did not worked

```
deny{
   r := tfplan.resource_changes[_]
   r.type == "aws_msk_cluster"
   name := r.change.after.encryption_info[_]
   #val := walk(name,["encryption_in_transit"],"TLS")
   print(name)
   #print(val)
   contains(name,"TLS")
}
```

Mock.json

```
"change": {
                    "actions": [
                        "create"
                    ],
                    "before": null,
                    "after": {
                        "broker_node_group_info": [
                            {
                                "az_distribution": "DEFAULT",
                                "instance_type": "kafka.m5.large",
                                "storage_info": [
                                    {
                                        "ebs_storage_info": [
                                            {
                                                "provisioned_throughput": [],
                                                "volume_size": 1000
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "client_authentication": [],
                        "cluster_name": "example",
                        "configuration_info": [],
                        "encryption_info": [
                            {
                                "encryption_in_transit": [
                                    {
                                        "client_broker": "TLS",
                                        "in_cluster": true
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "enhanced_monitoring": "DEFAULT",
                        "kafka_version": "3.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue by the below line of code

```
is_encryption_in_transit{
   r := tfplan.resource_changes[_]
   r.type == "aws_msk_cluster"
   name := r.change.after.encryption_info[_]
   [path,val] := walk(name.encryption_in_transit)
   protocol = val["client_broker"]
   cluster_encryption = val["in_cluster"]
   protocol == "TLS"
   cluster_encryption == true
}
```